# What do you call this captive bolt fixing (UK)?

Tags: wooden-furniture

There's a captive bolt (or in this particular case - headless bolt that screws into socket in the frame) and there's a sort of angled brace piece that gets tightened against the cavity and then a long nut.

I bought these chairs second hand and a couple of these bits are missing. Trying to work out what they are properly called so I can buy replacement...

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the washer, search for *half moon washer*.

Most of what you will find is shaped a little different from yours, but has the same purpose. I would use a regular washer and nut on top of this.

Unfortunately, I didn't find any that indicated the radius of the curve. Maybe there is a standard (?).

[image]

Comment: thanks, that looks like what I need 

Answer (score 0):

They are studs and nuts, with a curved washer to spread the load.

The stud has a wood thread one end and a machined thread either English or metric the other.